# Add own code to a Visual Studio Setup Project?

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I use Visio Studio 2008 and have a problem with the Setup Project.
It is possible to add own code to this project?
My problem is that I must set Folder Permissions and the PowerShell command Set-ExcetuingPolicy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Custom Action in the deployment project:

[Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There's an [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for that.